# Angularjs <script> received via json place in HTML code

Tags: html, angularjs

I have seen quite a few similar questions but they all seem to be related to `<p>` tags and are not working for scripts.

The below snippet is a e-signable pdf - it is not rendering in here for some reason but if placed in a `.html` it would just be a basic pdf with 2 signable fields.

```html
<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://secure.eu1.echosign.com/public/embeddedWidget?wid=CBFCIBAA3AAABLblqZhBErQXBc488fW6dc9TExmomSqMLibzpk1duAQnawv3c1xGBoAjI-zvPUGWe1goCLs0*'></script>
```

I receive the script via json and I am trying to embed it onto a html page on when it is returned. I am using `ngSanitize` This is what I have tried so far...

Angular:

```
vm.someFunction = function () {
       $http({
                url: 'https://api.eu1.echosign.com/api/rest/v5/widgets',
                method: "POST",
                data:
                    {
                       // ... json data 

                    }
            }).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data;
                    $scope.script = {content : response.data.javascript };
                }
            )};
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCntrl as vm">
    <p ng-bind-html="script.content"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using:

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://pdf.test/input.html");
myWindow.document.write($scope.script);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that link it is returning a javascript function as a string.

```
document.write('<iframe src="https://secure.eu1.echosign.com/public/esignWidget?wid=CBFCIBAA3AAABLblqZhBErQXBc488fW6dc9TExmomSqMLibzpk1duAQnawv3c1xGBoAjI-zvPUGWe1goCLs0*&hosted=false&token=&firstName=&lastName=&nameEditable=true" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border: 0; overflow: hidden; min-height: 500px; min-width: 600px;"></iframe>');
```

you can do is eval:

```
eval($scope.script.content)
```

but there is a problem your webpage get overridden by the eval code.

the best way is to open a new tab, get the reference of opener property.

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.opener.window.eval($scope.script.content);
```

Comment: opening a new tab but stays blank